# How to test extra_hosts configuration?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

How can I check if my extra_hosts configuration is working?

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I tried `docker exec nginx /bin/sh -c 'ping host.docker.internal'`

but got `/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found`

Is there some kind of ping alternative available in the nginx docker image?

Testing on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS host, with docker version 20.10.11 and docker-compose version 1.29.2.

Comment: Usually if you have an Nginx reverse proxy, it'll send TCP (HTTP) messages to somewhere, not ICMP (ping) packets.  Can you just make a call through the HTTP endpoint that proxies back to the host?

Comment: I'm getting 504 Gateway Timeout, but I don't know whether this means that my proxy configuration is wrong or if the certbot standalone docker run is not serving or if the port-mapping is faulty. I just now got it to work with webroot, but would still be interested in debugging this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx image does not come with ping command, you can add a busybox to test in and out:

```
cat << EOF > docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    command: ash -c 'sleep 3600'
EOF

docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec busybox ping host.docker.internal
docker-compose exec busybox wget -qO- nginx
docker-compose exec busybox wget -qO- host.docker.internal:8080
docker-compose down
```

Comment: command 'bash' not 'ash' right?

Comment: nope, use `ash`.

Comment: ok, didn't know about that one

Comment: thanks, i created (just) a busybox and ping returns 172.17.0.1 for host.docker.internal, so I'm pretty sure that part is not the problem with my nginx container.

Comment: If you happen to use docker run, the equivalent to extra_hosts is `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway`. You can change busybox to alpine if you need more testing utilities in the future.

Comment: i'm using `docker-compose up` for nginx, and `docker-compose run --rm --service-ports` for the certbot container

Answer (score 1):

Always use **sidecar** container & do not overwhelm the main image:

k8s community provides a good image for network debugging which includes almost all famous CLIs : dig, nslookup, ping,.etc

```
 k8s.gcr.io/e2e-test-images/jessie-dnsutils:1.3
```

Use it the same way the busybox way explained by [gohm'c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70269236/747579)